# Concurrent changes in silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe, rowversion

do you have any experience with implementation of RowVersion in Silverstripe framework or how you solved this problem in php? I´m using Silverstripe framework version 3.6 and PHP version 5.5.7 with MySQL DB.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a bit more context about what you're trying to achieve if you want some help with this problem

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Can you please describe your problem better? What do you try to acchieve? SilverStripe has a built in versioning system you can use for DataObjects, see https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/versioning/

Comment: I'd recommend: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-multiuser-editing-alert

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, I suppose you would like to prevent multiple users editing the same record in the same time... and if that's the case, you might want to have a look on this module: https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-editlock